# How to transfer file from one server to another using sftp in Magento 2?

Tags: php, magento2, sftp

I want to transfer all the images associated to that product from M1 to M2 using sftp. I can connect to M1 using sftp. But I am not getting how to transfer it.

Here is a code to connect with sftp -

```
//FTP Connection
public function connectFtp($host, $user, $password, $ssl=true, $passive=true){
        return $connect = $this->sftp->open(
            array(
                'host'      =>  $host,
                'user'      =>  $user,
                'password'  =>  $password,
                'ssl'       =>  $ssl,
                'passive'   =>  $passive
            )
        );
    }
```

```
//Downlaod images from M1 and transfer to M2 temp folder
    public function downloadImages($images){
        //Connecting to M1
        $connect = $this->connectFtp(SELF::M1_HOST, SELF::M1_USERNAME, SELF::M1_PASSWORD, SELF::M1_SSL, SELF::M1_PASSIVE);
        if($connect){
           /* Code to transfer */
        }
    }
```

How to achieve this file transfer? As per some project requirements, we don't want to use any plugin.

Answer (score 0):

Do you just want to transfer ALL the images from M1 to M2?

You can try to rsync the images across instead:

```
rsync user@m1.host:/path/to/copy user@m2.host:/path/to/copy
```

Answer (score 0):

Working code for File transfer from SFTP server to Our Server.

```
  $sftp = $obj->create('Magento\Framework\Filesystem\Io\Sftp');
  $open =  $sftp->open(
       array(
           'host' => $sftp_hostname,
           'username' => $sftp_username,
           'password' => $sftp_password,
           'port'=>$sftp_port
       )
    );

    try{
        // Change directory and move to require directory
        $sftp->cd('/enter_your_sftp_file_path_here/');

        //Fetching/Listing all the files.
        $sftp_server_files = $sftp->ls();

        //File path to put files from SFTP Server to our local server
        $filepath = $dir->getRoot() . '/var/import/inventory/';

        foreach ($sftp_server_files as $file) {

            //Copy files from server
            $source = $file['text'];
            if(strpos($source, 'zip') !== false){
                $destination = $filepath.$source;
                $result = $sftp->read($source, $destination);
                if($result == 'true') {
                   $message[] = 'File read from SFTP server : '.$source;
                }
                else
                {
                  $message[] = 'File not able to read from SFTP server : '.$source;
                }
            }
        }
    } catch ( Exception $e) {
        echo $e->getMessage();
    }
```